# Unknown error in GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I'm writing a module in GWT. It uses a WYSIWYG editor. It was running smoothly until I tried using RichText from GWT instead of WYSIWYG editor. Since it did not workout as expected, I rolled back to the old code (i.e. WYSIWYG). But now, when I run the compiled html file in a browser, I get an error

`Error: a is null Source File: http://www.xxxxx.com/sandbox/rss-manager/rss_manager/88DF3622F3340D0F082021E59419F325.cache.html
Line: 1022`

It isn't showing any errors during compile time either. Its hard to figure out what the problem is.

Please help

Comment: I'm using the WYSIWYG editor as a separate JAR file. I have imported the JAR file and added a inherits section `<inherits name="com.gc.gwt.wysiwyg.Editor" />`. 

I'm using eclipse. Its showing a warning


`The following classpath entry 'D:\workspace\RSS Manager\src\com\fiorano\rss\shared\editor-0.1.4.jar' will not be available on the server's classpath`

Answer (score 2):

Try to compile your code in PRETTY or DETAILED style.
If error repeats, you'll be able to find exact place where it happens.

P.

Comment: I hope no one has got this problem.

GWT behaves strangely at certain occasions. Anyhow I got my solution. Thanks a lot guys. It was a Async call which was making all the problems. Had to redesign the whole structure a bit.

Comment: It was a LOGICAL ERROR. GWT not to be blamed